# Stop processing and return error message if file is empty in Mule

Tags: exception, mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I am using Anypoint Studio 6.1 and Mule 3.8.1 and have a workflow which processes a number of files.  The files are sequential and must be processed in order so each file is processed through a for each loop.

If the first line of the body of the CSV file (line 4) is missing then I need processing to stop and no more files processed and an error message to be passed back in the response.

What components can I use to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the error message you just answered your own question.
Just throw exception with required message. Like this:

```
<scripting:transformer doc:name="Script">
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[throw new Exception('File is empty')]]></scripting:script>
</scripting:transformer>
```

Of course you should use your own logic. Something like

```
if line[4]==null throw new Exception('File is empty')
```